# Not updating after adding class to div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some `div` and whenever the input is valid, it should add a green tick to the `div`, like this:

```js
function ValidateEmail() {
    var regex = /(([a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.?){1,3})(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}){1,3})/
    var email = document.getElementById("reg_email").value;
    if (email.indexOf("..") == -1 && email.match(regex)) {
        reg_email_v.classList.add('validated');
        return true;
    }
    reg_email_v.classList.remove('validated');
    reg_email_v.innerHTML = "";
    return false;
}
```

```css
.input-validation 
{
    display: inline-block;
    color:Green;
    content:"";
}
.input-validation.validated
{
    content: "123";
    color: Green;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="reg_email" runat="server" maxlength="100" onkeyup="ValidateEmail();" />
<div class="input-validation" id="reg_email_v"></div>
```

When I add `validated` to the `div`'s classes, it updates in the browser itself, but nothing shows up in the actual `div`.. Both the `div` and the `input` are in one `td` inside a table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`content` can be used only with `:after` and `:before` pseudo classes. So

```
.input-validation.validated:before
{
    content: "123";
    color: Green;
}
```

should work